# Find file without spaces in file name

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to find all *.cpp, using `find` files under current directory, which do not contain spaces in neither dirname nor basename. I understand I need to use `-wholename` flag, but I can not find an appropriate regex syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `find` with a regex:

```
find . -type f -regex "[^ ]*.cpp"
```